# Looking for Firebird GUI

Tags: database, firebird

I use phpMyAdmin to manage all of my MySQL databases and SQL Management Studio Express to manage my MS SQL databases.  Now I need to start working with Firebird, and I'm looking for a tool along the lines of SQL Management Studio to manage those databases as well.

I can be flexible with the UI and can learn a new system, so if there's something *freely* available that will do the trick but isn't quite the same as SQL management Studio I think I could adapt.

Bottom line: What free tools are available that provide an in-depth GUI for Firebird?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's list of tools for Firebird on their website

http://www.ibphoenix.com/resources/projects/

There are plenty of good ones, both open source and commercial.  Some are limited solely to Firebird, some can work with many different databases (i.e, MySQL, MSSQL, and Firebird all with same tool), and some are cross platform and/or Java- and/or web-based.

[DBWorkbench](http://www.upscene.com/database_workbench/) is a first class commercial product that could work with MySQL, MSSQL, and Firebird.  They have a free "lite" version that's restricted to one db, you might check out that one for Firebird: